# Why does this C code throw a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have the following `c` code

```
void *curr = (unsigned long *)some_fixed_address;
if (!curr) {*(unsigned long *)curr = a^b;}
```

where `some_fixed_address` stores long integer `0`, and `a` and `b` are some predefined integers. When I run this code I get an error

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

Is there any reason why this might be the case?

Update:

Here is the minimal verifiable example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    size_t start = 0;
    size_t a = 5;
    size_t b = 100;
    void *curr = (char *)start;
    if (!curr) {*(unsigned long *)curr = a^b;}
    printf("%d", *(int *)curr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by `some_fixed_address`? Is this for an embedded system?

Comment: If `some_fixed_address` is null, then you create a null pointer and try to dereference it, thus the segmentation fault.

Comment: He said that `some_fixed_address` stores `0`.

Comment: I think he has provided enough information to answer correctly

Comment: It is highly probably that the error is not in the code you provided. More context to this code and a MCVE would be relevant. This is a good opportunity to learn on how to use a debugger and step through your code.

Comment: @KamilCuk Well, OP's snippet (given what's stated in the question) looks a lot like `void *p = 0; if (!p) *(int *)p = 42;`. That's enough to spot an error IMHO, but yes, an MCVE is always needed.

Comment: Why are you casting `some_fixed_address` to an `unsigned long *`, then assigning that to a `void *`, then casting that again to an `unsigned long *`?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I have added a MCVE.

Comment: ok now you have clarified. As my answer says, this code is guaranteed to fail. You cannot deference a NULL pointer (0 in most modern CPUs) and your code explicitly (if somewhat indirectly) tries to do that

Answer (score 3):

On your machine, `NULL` is probably bitwise equal to `0` (although the standard doesn't require this).

So when you convert `some_fixed_address` to a pointer, you end up with a pointer full of `0`, which is the `NULL` pointer.

`!curr` then checks that `curr` is `NULL`. You then try to dereference `curr` in the body of the `if` statement, which causes a SEGFAULT.

Comment: What is `bitwise NULL` and why do you mention NULL at all? There is no NULL in the OP.

Comment: `if (!curr)` is analogous to `if (curr == NULL)`

Comment: I do not think `some_fixed_address == 0`, I think question means `*some_fixed_address==0` (in OP's mind)

Comment: @DYZ I meant to type 'bitwise equal to 0`, meaning that every bit in a NULL pointer is a 0.

Comment: @pm100 rereading, I think you might be right, but it's very unclear. Hoping that OP can clarify for us so I can update this accordingly.

Comment: I have clarified my question.

Comment: @pm100 looks like I interpreted the original post correctly.

Comment: @dipankar looks like I interpreted the original post correctly. This answer should explain everything. Let me know if you have any trouble understanding anything, or except my answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso But all I am trying to do is to initialize the value of `curr` pointer to some value `a^b`. How can modify my code to achieve this?

Comment: @dipankar do you want `curr` to point to a memory location storing `a^b`? It's very unclear what you're trying to do

Answer (score 2):

The only logical explanation given what you have shown us is that `some_fixed_address` is zero, which is not addressable, hence the segfault.

Your `if (!curr) { ... }` couldn't execute otherwise -- it *only* executes if `curr` is `0`.

I wonder if you got your `if` statement's logic backwards.  (Or you haven't provided enough information and your bug lies elsewhere.)

Answer (score 1):

well this code makes no sense

```
void *curr = (unsigned long *)some_fixed_address;
if (!curr) {*(unsigned long *)curr = a^b;} <<< only if curr is null then try to do something with it
```

I think you mean

```
void *curr = (unsigned long *)some_fixed_address;
if (curr) {*(unsigned long *)curr = a^b;} <<<< if curr is not null then try to do something
```

However the fact that you were getting the error on that line strongly suggests that some_fixed_address is 0. So the 'corrected' code above will run, but will do nothing.